# My ear speaker doesn't detected in my Angular app (using enumerateDevices)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, html5-audio

I am building a project with Ionic 5 / Angular.
I want to build a voice call app, which needs to access my phone ear speaker, not the loudspeaker.

The problem is when I fetch my device's audio output using `enumerateDevices()`, I don't find any other audio output besides the default audio output (the loudspeaker itself).

[image: IO Devices]

I want to attach the HTMLMediaElement using [.setSinkId()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId) to the ear speaker's device ID, but didn't find it. Is there any native plugin or workaround for this? Or is it just my phone that doesn't support it? Currently, I am using Samsung Galaxy A51.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/danielflippance/audiotoggle#readme

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Thank you, it is working for now in my app , just hoping no major bugs or problems will occur.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Should i post it as Answer? accept it so other people can get help.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib approved your answer :). Hoping this plugin can get direct support into ionic native API, and get more support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Plugin: [Github Repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle)

NPM : [Npm LInk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle)

Usage:

```
AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.SPEAKER);
// or
AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EARPIECE);
```